# One java file use another java file compile error

Tags: java

ubuntu version: 12.04  java version 1.7

FPTree.java contents:

```
package fptree;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;


public class FPTree extends TreeNode {  


    private int minSuport;

    public int getMinSuport() {
        return minSuport;
    }

    public void setMinSuport(int minSuport) {
        this.minSuport = minSuport;
    }


    public List<List<String>> readTransRocords(String... filenames) {
        List<List<String>> transaction = null;
        if (filenames.length > 0) {
            transaction = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
            for (String filename : filenames) {
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    try {
                        String line;
                        List<String> record;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if(line.trim().length()>0){
                                String str[] = line.split(",");
                                record = new LinkedList<String>();
                                for (String w : str)
                                    record.add(w);
                                transaction.add(record);
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Read transaction records failed."
                            + ex.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return transaction;
    }


    public void FPGrowth(List<List<String>> transRecords,
            List<String> postPattern) {

        ArrayList<TreeNode> HeaderTable = buildHeaderTable(transRecords);

        TreeNode treeRoot = buildFPTree(transRecords, HeaderTable);

        if (treeRoot.getChildren()==null || treeRoot.getChildren().size() == 0)
            return;

        if(postPattern!=null){
            for (TreeNode header : HeaderTable) {
                System.out.print(header.getCount() + "\t" + header.getName());
                for (String ele : postPattern)
                    System.out.print("\t" + ele);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        for (TreeNode header : HeaderTable) {

            List<String> newPostPattern = new LinkedList<String>();
            newPostPattern.add(header.getName());
            if (postPattern != null)
                newPostPattern.addAll(postPattern);

            List<List<String>> newTransRecords = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
            TreeNode backnode = header.getNextHomonym();
            while (backnode != null) {
                int counter = backnode.getCount();
                List<String> prenodes = new ArrayList<String>();
                TreeNode parent = backnode;

                while ((parent = parent.getParent()).getName() != null) {
                    prenodes.add(parent.getName());
                }
                while (counter-- > 0) {
                    newTransRecords.add(prenodes);
                }
                backnode = backnode.getNextHomonym();
            }

            FPGrowth(newTransRecords, newPostPattern);
        }
    }


    public ArrayList<TreeNode> buildHeaderTable(List<List<String>> transRecords) {
        ArrayList<TreeNode> F1 = null;
        if (transRecords.size() > 0) {
            F1 = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
            Map<String, TreeNode> map = new HashMap<String, TreeNode>();

            for (List<String> record : transRecords) {
                for (String item : record) {
                    if (!map.keySet().contains(item)) {
                        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item);
                        node.setCount(1);
                        map.put(item, node);
                    } else {
                        map.get(item).countIncrement(1);
                    }
                }
            }

            Set<String> names = map.keySet();
            for (String name : names) {
                TreeNode tnode = map.get(name);
                if (tnode.getCount() >= minSuport) {
                    F1.add(tnode);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(F1);
            return F1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public TreeNode buildFPTree(List<List<String>> transRecords,
            ArrayList<TreeNode> F1) {
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
        for (List<String> transRecord : transRecords) {
            LinkedList<String> record = sortByF1(transRecord, F1);
            TreeNode subTreeRoot = root;
            TreeNode tmpRoot = null;
            if (root.getChildren() != null) {
                while (!record.isEmpty()
                        && (tmpRoot = subTreeRoot.findChild(record.peek())) != null) {
                    tmpRoot.countIncrement(1);
                    subTreeRoot = tmpRoot;
                    record.poll();
                }
            }
            addNodes(subTreeRoot, record, F1);
        }
        return root;
    }

    public LinkedList<String> sortByF1(List<String> transRecord,
            ArrayList<TreeNode> F1) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String item : transRecord) {

            for (int i = 0; i < F1.size(); i++) {
                TreeNode tnode = F1.get(i);
                if (tnode.getName().equals(item)) {
                    map.put(item, i);
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>> al = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(
                map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> arg0,
                    Entry<String, Integer> arg1) {

                return arg0.getValue() - arg1.getValue();
            }
        });
        LinkedList<String> rest = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : al) {
            rest.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        return rest;
    }


    public void addNodes(TreeNode ancestor, LinkedList<String> record,
            ArrayList<TreeNode> F1) {
        if (record.size() > 0) {
            while (record.size() > 0) {
                String item = record.poll();
                TreeNode leafnode = new TreeNode(item);
                leafnode.setCount(1);
                leafnode.setParent(ancestor);
                ancestor.addChild(leafnode);

                for (TreeNode f1 : F1) {
                    if (f1.getName().equals(item)) {
                        while (f1.getNextHomonym() != null) {
                            f1 = f1.getNextHomonym();
                        }
                        f1.setNextHomonym(leafnode);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                addNodes(leafnode, record, F1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FPTree fptree = new FPTree();
        fptree.setMinSuport(3);
        List<List<String>> transRecords = fptree
                .readTransRocords("/home/steven/automata/test.txt");
        fptree.FPGrowth(transRecords, null);
    }
}
```

TreeNode.java file contents

```
package fptree;

import java.util.TN_ArrayList;
import java.util.TN_List;

    public class TreeNode implements Comparable<TreeNode> {


        private String name; 
        private int count; 
        private TreeNode parent;
        private TN_List<TreeNode> children;
        private TreeNode nextHomonym;

        /*  
        public TreeNode() {

        }
        */
        public TreeNode(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public TreeNode getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(TreeNode parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public TN_List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public void addChild(TreeNode child) {
            if (this.getChildren() == null) {
                TN_List<TreeNode> list = new TN_ArrayList<TreeNode>();
                list.add(child);
                this.setChildren(list);
            } else {
                this.getChildren().add(child);
            }
        }

        public TreeNode findChild(String name) {
            TN_List<TreeNode> children = this.getChildren();
            if (children != null) {
                for (TreeNode child : children) {
                    if (child.getName().equals(name)) {
                        return child;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void setChildren(TN_List<TreeNode> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }

        public void printChildrenName() {
            TN_List<TreeNode> children = this.getChildren();
            if (children != null) {
                for (TreeNode child : children) {
                    System.out.print(child.getName() + " ");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("null");
            }
        }

        public TreeNode getNextHomonym() {
            return nextHomonym;
        }

        public void setNextHomonym(TreeNode nextHomonym) {
            this.nextHomonym = nextHomonym;
        }

        public void countIncrement(int n) {
            this.count += n;
        }


        public int compareTo(TreeNode arg0) {

            int count0 = arg0.getCount();

            return count0 - this.count;
        }
    }
```

when i type compile command : javac -d . FPTree.java, it appear error following

```
FPTree.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
public class FPTree extends TreeNode {  
                            ^
  symbol: class TreeNode
FPTree.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
    public ArrayList<TreeNode> buildHeaderTable(List<List<String>> transRecords) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList<TreeNode> F1) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
    public TreeNode buildFPTree(List<List<String>> transRecords,
           ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:167: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList<TreeNode> F1) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:196: error: cannot find symbol
    public void addNodes(TreeNode ancestor, LinkedList<String> record,
                         ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList<TreeNode> F1) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<TreeNode> HeaderTable = buildHeaderTable(transRecords);
                  ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        TreeNode treeRoot = buildFPTree(transRecords, HeaderTable);
        ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            for (TreeNode header : HeaderTable) {
                 ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
        for (TreeNode header : HeaderTable) {
             ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
            TreeNode backnode = header.getNextHomonym();
            ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
                TreeNode parent = backnode;
                ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<TreeNode> F1 = null;
                  ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
            F1 = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
                               ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
            Map<String, TreeNode> map = new HashMap<String, TreeNode>();
                        ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
            Map<String, TreeNode> map = new HashMap<String, TreeNode>();
                                                            ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
                        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item);
                        ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
                        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item);
                                            ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
                TreeNode tnode = map.get(name);
                ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:147: error: cannot find symbol
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(); 
        ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:147: error: cannot find symbol
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
                            ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
            TreeNode subTreeRoot = root;
            ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:151: error: cannot find symbol
            TreeNode tmpRoot = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
                TreeNode tnode = F1.get(i);
                ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:201: error: cannot find symbol
                TreeNode leafnode = new TreeNode(item);
                ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:201: error: cannot find symbol
                TreeNode leafnode = new TreeNode(item);
                                        ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
FPTree.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
                for (TreeNode f1 : F1) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class TreeNode
  location: class FPTree
28 errors
```

my test.txt file contents:

```
1,2,3,5
2,3,5
4,5,6
2,4,6
1,3,5,8
```

how to solve the problem? please help me

Comment: What's your JDK version? What IDE are you using? Try Eclipse?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O works fine :) of course if you use Eclipse...

Comment: Make sure all required classes are on the classpath.

Comment: @Kieveli the jdk version is irrelevant, as is the ide

Comment: Are the files in the same directory?  If your answer is no, than put them in the same directory.

Comment: I just use ubuntu to install openjdk7, and i don't use the eclipse to implement, just compile at terminal.

Comment: The source of the problem is that `TreeNode` class failed to compile due to `import java.util.TN_ArrayList` and `java.util.TN_List`. OR you did not try to compile it at all and tried to compile only the `FPTree` class by itself which, of course, fails.

Comment: of course two java file and txt are the same directory

Comment: @NimChimpsky The IDE, like Eclipse, would have highlighted the error - I noticed he was missing the includes for the TreeNode, but didn't have time to add more.  Since he didn't see the include missing, I assumed no IDE, and also a low level of experience. You're probably right about the JDK though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to manually call the compiler, make sure to build in a proper output directory (not `.`), use it as with a `-classpath` argument, and compile the classes in the right order (`TreeNode` before `FPTree`).

Or use `ant`, `maven`, or an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling your code from one folder upper:

```
javac parent/FPTree.java
```

or you can use this commands:

```
javac -classpath . *.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling `TreeNode.java` first, since `FPTree.java` depends on it. You shouldn't need to do do that (IIRC), but what the heck. Also, when compiling FPTree, use the `-cp .` option to tell the compiler where it can find the class file for TreeNode.

Of course, you also could just use Maven and make your life a **lot** easier...

Comment: Using Maven won't make his life easier for this tiny little problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Obviously, if he used Maven he wouldn't have this problem at all.

Comment: Suggesting Maven as a solution for a beginning Java programmer is silly on the face of it. You have to know how things actually work before using Maven, otherwise you won't be able to solve Maven problems. Even an empty Maven archetype is over the head of a person new to programming. There's nothing "easier" about throwing Maven at a person that doesn't even know how to compile two files from the command line.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Then how come many tutorials (and college courses) use it for beginning programmers? And isn't there something more constructive you can be doing than belittling other people's suggestions?

Comment: @DaveNewton: and on a less combative note, the problem with your argument is that while teaching how things really work is fine, you run the risk of overwhelming beginners with "too many moving parts" if you do it for everything at once. That's why many courses have students use Maven or an IDE at first, to hide these details from students. And to be honest, many professors never teach these details. Their reasoning is that they are here to teach Computer Science concepts and they are not a "vocational school".

Comment: Two classes and a classpath argument is nearly as simple as Java gets. Maven complicates the issue by (a) hiding mechanisms, (b) requiring additional software to be installed, and (c) obfuscating problems when they occur. I can almost live with the use of an IDE for the absolute beginner, but they're not a substitute for understanding what's actually happening, which is critical for deep learning. Maven for this is a bad joke. It's significantly harder, and has significantly more moving parts, than just compiling from the command line.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Just because you state something like it's a fact doesn't make it true. Clearly, many people whose job it is to know more about this than either of us disagree.

Comment: @DaveNewton: And of course the basic argument: If Maven just makes things more complicated, why would people use it?

Comment: Not too many people know more about this than I do, statistically speaking. Your spurious argument "If Maven is so complicated why do people use it" isn't relevant here: Maven's purpose is to manage complexities that do not exist in this question.

Comment: The "basic" argument that I'm making is that people that don't understand how things are actually working (easier to teach when problems are simple) are missing underlying information. Adding a layer of obfuscation is intrinsically bad. The classpath is a *Java fundamental*. Anyone that refuses to acknowledge or teach the fundamentals is being irresponsible.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Clearly, what you just said is not true. Proof is the fact that the asker had a problem that Maven would have eliminated.

Comment: ... By introducing an entirely new set of problems the OP is completely unequipped to solve. Teaching *why* it works the way it does provides (some) of the requisite knowledge required to solve Maven-related problems. *That* is vocational work. *How things work* is education. *Specific tools* is vocational. If you'd rather hand people fish, that's fine, but it's the mark of a poor educator that thinks it's better than teaching someone to fish.

Comment: @DaveNewton: do you know exactly how your car works? If it broke down could you fix it yourself? Yet clearly a car makes life simpler. That argument is specious.

Comment: I've rebuilt two engines, so I'd hazard a guess I'd get pretty far along in the process before needing to call in an expert. "Cars make life simpler" -- that's funny, because in many areas, and for many reasons, they actually complicate life immensely, e.g., NYC. Do you start off driving a car on the highway, or do you take baby steps and understand the fundamentals of driving, and the rules of the road first? The latter: what makes driving a car possible, and the rules around said activity, are learned first.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Now you're arguing simply to argue. As you well know, none of your previous response was germane to the point made. Your whole agenda here is to prove you're a smart guy, so you couldn't resist saying, "yeah, I'm an expert at cars, too!" This is confirmed when you say things like "Not too many people know more about this than I do," and the fact that you commented here at all. I'm sorry, but if want to prove you're a smart guy you need to do better than to doggedly circle back to the same "it's too complicated" argument instead of actually addressing the points given to refute it.

Comment: ... I did, and you've answered none of mine. I have nothing to "prove", I think you're wrong, badly. I gave you the reasons I believe this. All you've said is "oh but if he'd used Maven he wouldn't have this problem", and completely ignored every single one of my points, even when I use your own analogy to show you *why* you should learn the basics first. Good luck!

Comment: @DaveNewton: In case it wasn't clear enough for you from my previous comment, this conversation's over.

Comment: *lol* You're funny :) It's too bad you're unable to actually address a single point I've actually made, instead relying on failed analogies (that argue against yourself) and telling me why I'm arguing--typical deflections. Regarding the "vocational" part; anybody using Java to teach CS is *already* vocational, since Java is a poor language choice for teaching CS--it doesn't have the abstractions necessary to do a good job of it. There's a reason good schools use languages like Scheme and Python to teach fundamentals.

Comment: But yes, blissfully, this folly is over. I'll compile the responses I'm getting offline for you, though; while I'd hope they'd be helpful for you, I kind of doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Something to *remark and remind*:

> When juggling with packages, do not sit inside such a package! You have to be outside!

Your compiling command `javac -d . FPTree.java` contains a tiny hint on where you are. The option `-d .` could mean that you are sitting in a directory called `fptree`, which represents the package.

Having a directory structure like that

```
<project_root>
      |
      |--- src/
      |     |--- fptree/
      |     |       |--- TreeNode.java
      |     |       |--- FPTree.java
      |
      |--- bin/
```

then the best way to compile your program is as following: Change to the *project root* directory. From there you invoke the java compiler with

> javac -d bin -sourcepath src TreeNode.java FPTree.java